# Which collection to use to store and search a million record in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I would like to know which is the right collection to be used in Java to store and search string/data from millions of data?

1. Assume you want it for String.
2. Assume you want it for objects, and search for multiple values.

Please note that I am looking for the best performance to quickly get the search result. I am looking for Java collection which can do this. Want to know the right collection that can be used. Input is an arbitrary string and not necessarily sorted.

Comment: What are the search criteria?  That will most likely determine which data structure is best.

Comment: _"millions of data"_ - how big is the data? Will it still fit into your memory? Your question is super broad, I am voting to close it, it can not be answered precisely.

Comment: Are your strings just random sets of characters or human's language words?

Comment: _"objects, and search for multiple values"_ - like looking for arbitrary objects and searching for arbitrary fields of them? Are the fields strings, ints, or more arbitrary objects?

Comment: Are you looking for `Collections` solutions (since you used the tag) or also for external storage solutions like databases?

Comment: "Best performance" is ALWAYS a tradeoff, what is the actual performance you want to achieve, how much are you willing to pay for the task to complete? You can do it in 100$ or 100 billion $ if you create multiple data centers around the globe so that the performance is best, maybe even shoot satellites into space... This question is too broad.

Comment: @Zabuzard I am looking for a borad answer in the context of using Java collection. I want to know different perspectives on it. Kindly open this thread.

Comment: SO is not the place to ask broad questions, please see [ask]. You may be better off asking in some other place then.

Comment: You should not ask questions like this basically anywhere, not before you have thought about what specific goals you want to achieve. "Best performance" does not exist and is not a valid goal. This question is rightfully downvoted and closed and will be deleted in the near future.

Comment: What is so broad about the question? Kindly let me know what specifics you are looking for?

I have clearly mentioned I want to know which collection to use for searching a string from a collection of sting.

Comment: **No, you did not mention anything clearly**. You still did not mention about the size of the data, the access pattern or ***ANY*** performance measurement you want to optimize.

Comment: This was an open-ended question I got for an interview. I wanted to know how to approach it. I will change with the appropriate assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you want to search in such large data structure, none of the available collections in java would be sufficient as you would need to store all the data in memory which would require really powerfull computer to work.

However there are existing solutions to you problem, which is called Full Text Search.

Take a look at [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) (which uses Apache Lucene under the hood)

For more simple solution you could also use any relational database which should also do the trick.

Comment: While this answer is useful in general, its not clear whether it addresses any of the things OP actually wants (bc the question is just unclear). So it is unclear whether it is actually useful for OPs specific question. You should avoid posting answers to unclear questions - you might get downvotes for that.

Comment: We have the year 2020. A million objects is not an impressive number. The answer should be, almost every built-in collection can deal with that number.